# Ошибка z-index'а в фиксированном div'е

Tags: javascript, css

Есть два блока с абсолютным позиционированием и один input range с зависимым, они накладываются друг на друга в порядке по возрастанию: блок1->блок2->range, через z-index, разумеется. И оно работает. Но когда я вкладываю эти элементы в другой элемент с фиксированым или абсолютным позиционированием, зависимый элемент (input range) опускается под два других, игнорируя z-index. Как исправить?

Код:

```css
#player {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

#progress {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 200;
}

#range {
  position: absolute;
  width: 86%;
  z-index: 100;
}

#duration {
  position: relative;
  width: 86%;
  z-index: 300;
}
```

```html
<div id="player">
  <div id="progress"></div>
  <div id="range"></div>
  <input type="range" id="duration" />
</div>
```

В общем виде. Значения положения на странице и т. д. рассчитывается в js.

Comment: Сегодня у телепатов выходной, для простых смертных, покажите ваш  HTML + CSS код

Comment: Arsen, HTML: `<div id="player"><div id="progress"></div><div id="range"></div><input type="range" id="duration" /></div>` CSS: `#player { position: fixed; bottom: 0; width: 100%; } #progress { position: absolute; z-index: 200; } #range { position: absolute; width: 86%; z-index: 100; } #duration { position: relative; width: 86%; z-index: 300; }` В общем виде. Значения положения на странице и т. д. высчитуется в js.

Comment: Разметку нужно не в комментарии добавлять, а в сам вопрос.

Comment: Cheg, ну ладно...

Comment: @Евгений данный код который вы показали, тут у вас не получается что то?
> Но когда я вкладываю эти элементы в другой элемент

Answer (score 0):

Я чего-то не понимаю, так как ваш код работает. По крайней мере в Chrome.

```css
#player {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

#progress {
  position: absolute;
  width: 60px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  z-index: 200;
}

#range {
  position: absolute;
  width: 120px;
  height: 100px;
  background: green;
  z-index: 100;
}

#duration {
  position: relative;
  width: 86%;
  z-index: 300;
}
```

```html
<div id="player">
  <div id="progress"></div>
  <div id="range"></div>
  <input type="range" id="duration" />
</div>
```